# How do I add an XML Map programmatically to an Excel 2010 Spreadsheet?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a basic XML file, which I need to add as an XML Map to an Excel 2010 Worksheet.

How do I do this programmatically? I would prefer a solution which uses Microsoft OpenXML SDK.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'map' an xml file to Excel?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a `CustomXmlMappingsPart` to your `WorkbookPart` and populate it with the schema for your XML.  Then you will need to add a `ConnectionsPart` that is linked to your xml file.

The below xml lives on my desktop in the file note.xml:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

This is the code to generate the xmlmappings

```
CustomXmlMappingsPart part = workbookPart.AddNewPart<CustomXmlMappingsPart>("rId8");

CustomXmlMappingsPart part = new 
MapInfo mapInfo1 = new MapInfo(){ SelectionNamespaces = "" };

Schema schema1 = new Schema(){ Id = "Schema1" };

OpenXmlUnknownElement openXmlUnknownElement1 = OpenXmlUnknownElement.CreateOpenXmlUnknownElement("<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><xsd:element nillable=\"true\" name=\"note\"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence minOccurs=\"0\"><xsd:element minOccurs=\"0\" nillable=\"true\" type=\"xsd:string\" name=\"to\" form=\"unqualified\" /><xsd:element minOccurs=\"0\" nillable=\"true\" type=\"xsd:string\" name=\"from\" form=\"unqualified\" /><xsd:element minOccurs=\"0\" nillable=\"true\" type=\"xsd:string\" name=\"heading\" form=\"unqualified\" /><xsd:element minOccurs=\"0\" nillable=\"true\" type=\"xsd:string\" name=\"body\" form=\"unqualified\" /></xsd:sequence></xsd:complexType></xsd:element></xsd:schema>");

schema1.Append(openXmlUnknownElement1);

Map map1 = new Map(){ ID = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "note_Map", RootElement = "note", SchemaId = "Schema1", ShowImportExportErrors = false, AutoFit = true, AppendData = false, PreserveAutoFilterState = true, PreserveFormat = true };
DataBinding dataBinding1 = new DataBinding(){ FileBinding = true, ConnectionId = (UInt32Value)1U, DataBindingLoadMode = (UInt32Value)1U };

map1.Append(dataBinding1);

mapInfo1.Append(schema1);
mapInfo1.Append(map1);

part.MapInfo = mapInfo1;
```

This code generates the connection and adds it to the `WorkbookPart`:

```
ConnectionsPart part = wookbookPart.AddNewPart<ConnectionsPart>("rId5");

Connections connections1 = new Connections();

Connection connection1 = new Connection(){ Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "note", Type = (UInt32Value)4U, RefreshedVersion = 0, Background = true };
WebQueryProperties webQueryProperties1 = new WebQueryProperties(){ XmlSource = true, SourceData = true, Url = "C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Desktop\\note.xml", HtmlTables = true, HtmlFormat = HtmlFormattingValues.All };

connection1.Append(webQueryProperties1);

connections1.Append(connection1);

part.Connections = connections1;
```

I generated this code with the Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool.  I compared a plain xlsx file with one that I added my simple XML map to.  Hope this helps.